# subprocess unable to capture STDOUT - what could be program be doing?

Tags: python

I have this program, which when executed on the console like this:

```
prog  1> output 2> error
```

Has the valid output and error. However, when I execute the same program using the subprocess module.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['prog'],stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,close_fds=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

The out is empty but err is proper. What could be happening here?
I can do a os.system and direct to output and error too. But I had been relying on subprocess for doing till recently.

What could be the problem? This is being tried on Linux only. Not on Windows.
`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying this on Windows?

The use of `close_fds` is
platform dependent, according to the [`subprocess.Popen()` doc](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

> If `close_fds` is true, all file descriptors except 0, 1 and 2 will be closed before the child process is executed. (Unix only). Or, on Windows, if close_fds is true then no handles will be inherited by the child process. **Note that on Windows, you cannot set close_fds to true and also redirect the standard handles by setting stdin, stdout or stderr**.

Comment: Nope, I am not trying on Windows. I am trying this on Linux.
Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your code and works for me:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
 close_fds=True)
>>> out, err = p.communicate()
>>> out
'build\nCode\n...'
>>> err
''
```

a) Make sure your program is called correctly.

b) Did you import PIPE correctly?

Comment: Yes, the program is called properly and PIPE is imported properly too.
It is not the problem at those ends. Thanks anyways.